# Automatic Unicode string formatting in Java

Tags: java, unicode, string-formatting

I just came across something like this:

```
String sample = "somejunk+%3cfoobar%3e+morestuff";
```

Printed out, sample looks like this:

> somejunk+`<foobar`>+morestuff

How does that work?  U+003c and U+003e are the Unicode codes for the less than and greater than signs, respectively, which seems like more than a coincidence, but I've never heard of Java automatically doing something like this.  I figured it'd be an easy thing to pop into Google, but it turns out Google doesn't like the percent sign.

Comment: Java doesn't do something like this. It looks like you're having an URL encoded String.

Comment: Yes, I would guess you saw it on a web page rather than in a source file which actually compiled :-)

Comment: How are you printing out and if stdout to what terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this,

```
    String sample = "somejunk+%3cfoobar%3e+morestuff";
    String result = URLDecoder.decode(sample.replaceAll("\\+", "%2B"), "UTF8");
```

Comment: Turns out that's close, it was actually being used as a Wicket ExternalLink in my case.  (http://wicket.apache.org/docs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/link/ExternalLink.html)

Answer (score 2):

That string is probably [URL encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) You'd decode that in java using the [URLDecoder](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html#decode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

```
String res = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(sample, "UTF8");
```

Answer (score 1):

Java does support Unicode escapes in `char` and `String` literals, but not URL encoding.

The Unicode escapes use `'\uXXXX'`, where XXXX is the Unicode point in hexadecimal.

Curious tidbit: The grammar allows `'u'` to occur multiple times, so that `'\uuuuuuuu0041'` is a valid Unicode escape (for `'A'`).